# For which rings $A$ is $A-\{0\}$ Diophantine over $A$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Recall that we call $S\subset A$ a *Diophantine* subset of $A$ if there exists a polynomial $P(t;x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with coefficients in $A$ such that: 
$$
t_0 \in S ~~ \Longleftrightarrow ~~ \textrm{$P(t_0;x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ has a solution in }A.
$$
My question: Is $A-\{0\}$ always Diophantine over $A$? And the follow-up: If not, for which $A$ do we have a positive answer?

For example, for $A$ a field we may take $P(t;x_1)=tx_1-1$ (per Noam Elkies' suggestion), so the answer is positive in this case. (For general $A$, however, this $P$ only shows that the *units* of $A$ are Diophantine.)

Comment: The sum-of-squares trick doesn't work over arbitrary rings, but you don't need it here: just say $P(t;x_1) = t x_1 - 1$.

Comment: I meant over general fields.  For arbitrary commutative rings with 1
it gives the units, as you noted.  For the ring of integers,
a simple (albeit not minimal) choice is
$$
P(t_0; x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) =
(t_0 - (x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2 + 1)) \,
(t_0 + (x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2 + 1)).
$$

Comment: In $A =\mathbb F_q[[t]]$, it seems to me that Diophantine sets must be closed in the $t$-adic topology, because the ring is compact and so projection maps are proper, so $A-\{0\}$ is not Diophantine. This argument probably generalizes to a Henselian DVR.

Comment: Very nice! (Could be an answer, really...)

Comment: Read the following paper by L. Moret-Bailly: Sur la définissabilité existentielle de la non-nullité dans les anneaux, Algebra and Number Theory. vol. 1, n° 3 (2007), 331-346.

Comment: A less interesting example is a product $A_1\times A_2$ of nontrivial rings. Though this does satisfy condition (C) of the paper of Moret-Bailly cited earlier, if $A_1$ and $A_2$ do.